# Rails.logger.info is not working in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, initializer

`Rails.logger.info` does not write any information to log when used in initializer.

How to get logging in initializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

before

```
MyServer::Application.initialize!
```

in `/config/environment.rb`

Comment: that only displays the messages to stdout and not to the logs.

Comment: @Paul, how would you change the output to a specific file, rather than stdout?

Answer (score 0):

May be the log level is silencing your message. Is it production or development?

Take a look to your `config.log_level` in your `config/*.yml` files