# Rails.logger usage from initializer in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5 application I am trying to access and use the logger in an initializer:

```
begin
  raise "REDIS_URL environment var not found" unless ENV["REDIS_URL"]
  $redis = Redis.new
  $redis.ping
  Rails.logger.info "Successfully connected to redis: #{ENV["REDIS_URL"]}" if $redis.connected?
rescue Exception => e
  Rails.logger.warn e.message
  Rails.logger.warn 'API only mode. Request to root will not return any index.html'
end
```

debugging inside the block I can access it:

```
(byebug) Rails.logger
#<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x007ffb69ef48d8>
(byebug) Rails.logger.level
0
(byebug)
```

but I don't see any msg in development. Is the logger supposed to be accessible but not to be used in there? Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377359/rails-logger-info-is-not-working-in-initializer#answer-26377540) this considered a correct solution?

**(It works in production)**

thank you